# Obtener valor de un select dentro de un componente livewire

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

Estoy realizando unas pruebas mediante componentes livewire y lo que necesito es obtener el valor de un select y mostrarlo en un , la parte de gestionar la carga del Select ya la tengo resuelta y funcionando, y lo que me está faltando es poder atrapar el valor del item seleccionado. Les muestro el código del componente.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Cliente;

class Clientes extends Component
{
    public $buscar;

    public function render()
    {
        $datos = Cliente::where('raz_social', 'like' , '%' . $this->buscar . '%')
        ->orderBy('raz_social')->get();

        return view('livewire.clientes', ['dtosclie' => $datos]);
    }
}
```

y acá la vista:

```
<div>
    <div class="flex flex-col">
        <input class="mb-1 bg-transparent border-0 border-b-2" type="text" placeholder="Nombre del cliente..." wire:model="buscar">
        <span>Aqui quiero poner el valor del cod_cli seleccionado</span>
        <select class="form-select rounded-lg">
            <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
            @foreach($dtosclie as $it)
                <option value="{{ $it->cod_cli}}">{{ $it->raz_social}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gracias y saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes crear un wire:model ***en la vista*** para el select.

`<select class="form-select rounded-lg" wire:model='selectedInput'>`

y en el controlador debes declarar ese modelo con valor nulo o vacío, para que no despliege nada hasta que tenga un valor, debería quedar algo así.

```
public $selectedInput = '';
```

Éxito